# how to initialize a CATransform3D with an array?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I have an array containing 16 float numbers, and I want to use this array to initialize the value of CATransform3D, i.e. m11, m12,....., is there any way to initialize it?

Answer (score 0):

`CATransform3D` is defined as this:

```
struct CATransform3D
{
  CGFloat m11, m12, m13, m14;
  CGFloat m21, m22, m23, m24;
  CGFloat m31, m32, m33, m34;
  CGFloat m41, m42, m43, m44;
};
```

Something like below should work:

```
CATransform3D myTransform;
myTransform.m11 = array[0];
myTransform.m12 = array[1];
myTransform.m13 = array[2];
myTransform.m14 = array[3];
myTransform.m21 = array[4];
myTransform.m22 = array[5];
myTransform.m23 = array[6];    
myTransform.m24 = array[7];
...
myTransform.m44 = array[15];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit dirty but you *can* do it like this:

```
CGFloat array[16];
...
CATransform3D myTransform;
memcpy(&myTransform, &array, sizeof(CATransform3D));
```